# Simple PHP application, Need clarification around Variable storing in $_SESSIONS

Tags: php, session

The Application is a simple guessing game that takes an input in the form and then compares it to a randomly generated number. Currently it works but with an error. The error being that it doesn't store the randomly generated number, but assigns a new one after each guess.

My question, I currently use multiple $_SESSION to store the different values, is this best practice? If so how can I store the randomly generated value and reuse it until the session is closed?

The other issue is the $num variable remains at 0, and doesn't actually increase.

Code for the game

```
<?

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["number"])) {
    $_SESSION["number"] = 0;
}
$num = $_SESSION["number"];
$message = $_SESSION["message"];

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Guessing Game</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Guessing Game</h1>
    <p>Enter a number between 1 and 100</p>

    <form Method="POST" action="guessProcess.php">
        <input type="number" name="guess" required>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guess">
    </form>

    <?= "<p>You have guessed " . $num . " of times<p>"; ?>
    <?= "<p> " . $message . " <p>"; ?>

    <br>
    <a href="giveup.php">Give Up</a><br><br>
    <a href="startover.php" >Start over</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php


?>
```

Code for the process

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["number"])) {
    $_SESSION["number"] = 0;
    $_SESSION["message"] = "";
}
$num = $_SESSION["number"];
$message = $_SESSION["message"];

$rand = rand(1,100);

$guess = $_POST['guess'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($submit)){

    if($guess >= 1 && $guess <= 100 && is_numeric($guess)){

        if($guess == $rand) {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Well Done, You have correctly guessed the number";
            $num++;
            $num = $_SESSION["number"];
            header("Location:guessinggame.php");
        } else if ($guess < $rand) {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Your guess is lower than the number";
            $num++;
            $num = $_SESSION["number"];
            header("Location:guessinggame.php");
        } else if ($guess > $rand) {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Your guess is higher than the number";
            $num++;
            $num = $_SESSION["number"];
            header("Location:guessinggame.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Your guess number must be between 1 and 100!";
            $num++;
            $num = $_SESSION["number"];
            header("Location:guessinggame.php");    
        }
    }
}
?>
<br><a href="startover.php">Start Over</a>
```

Startover.php just resets the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update 1**

Ok I understand that you're trying to store the solution. You can store it the same way you store the number of guesses: in `$_SESSION`.  Replace `$rand=rand(1,100)` with `$rand = isset($_SESSION['solution'])? $_SESSION['solution']: rand(1,100)`.  Or you could use the longer form and put the logic in an `if-else`

Remember at the end to re-store the solution (in case it was freshly created, it wouldn't be in `$_SESSION` unless we put it there). So at some point after the line above, you would do `$_SESSION['solution']=$rand`

**Original answer**

Your `$num` does not increase because after incrementing it with `$num++`, you reset it to its original value.  Instead of `$num = $_SESSION["number"]`, set the session's value to the new increment instead with `$_SESSION["number"]=$num`.  If the only purpose of `$num` is to increase the session value, just increment the session variable directly with `$_SESSION["number"]++`.  While you're at it, place that line outside of your `if-else` (since you're doing it in all branches, you might as well write that line only once)

You also mentioned that the application doesn't store the guess but assigns a new one. Could you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve: store the value and do what with it?  I notice that you capture it with `$guess = $_POST['guess']` and use it to check accuracy but you never store it in `$_SESSION` so I'm not sure I understand how you're trying to store it.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, the application takes a guess and compares it to the randomly generated number. The problem is the randomly generated number, generates a new number each time the person guesses. It should for eample, generate a random number X and maintain X and compare it the Guess. Currently it will generate X, then change to Y, then Z, then B each time the person makes a guess.

Comment: I see. how about adding `$_SESSION['solution']=$rand`?  Then it will be in the session and you can check for it instead of generating a new one with `rand(1,100)`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues were apparent: The random number is not being set in a session variable and the number of attempts is not being stored in the session variable "number."

I simplified the guessProcess.php script that resolves these and it seems to test okay:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["number"])) {
    $_SESSION["number"] = 0;
    $_SESSION["message"] = "";
}

if(!isset($_SESSION["rand"])) {
    $_SESSION["rand"] = rand(1, 100);
}

$guess = $_POST['guess'];

if(isset($guess)){

    if($guess >= 1 && $guess <= 100 && is_numeric($guess)){

            if($guess == $_SESSION["rand"]) {
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "Well Done, You have correctly guessed the number";
                    $_SESSION["number"]++;

                    header("Location:guessinggame.php");
            } else if ($guess < $_SESSION["rand"]) {
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "Your guess is lower than the number";
                    $_SESSION["number"]++;
                    header("Location:guessinggame.php");
            } else if ($guess > $_SESSION["rand"]) {
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "Your guess is higher than the number";
                    $_SESSION["number"]++;
                    header("Location:guessinggame.php");
            } else {
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "Your guess number must be between 1 and 100!";
                    $_SESSION["number"]++;
                    header("Location:guessinggame.php");
            }
    }
}
?>
<br><a href="startover.php">Start Over</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from everything, .. `If(isset($submit))`  that is apparently VERY much set/assigned just before the question about: is that damn thing set ? Where the hell all of the logic flew..? `$submit = $_POST['submit'];` ... without check first, is prone to fill that damn apache error_log file, doubt that not.

To clarify my spot on this very common noob mistake :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) // Always check - first
{
    $submit = $_POST['submit']; // Than - assign.
    // ...
    // ... 

}
```